# Blur TextInput when tapped outside of it

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm experiencing issue using `TextInput` expected behaviour is that when I tap on it, it is focused and keyboard is shown, and when I tap around it (anywhere besides the input), the TextInput should blur and keyboard will go away. At present this doesn't happen, text input stays focused no matter where I click. Is this expected behaviour, if so how is it usually handled?

```
<Image source={require('../assets/background.jpg')} style={{width: undefined; height: undefined; flex: 1;}}>
  <View>
    <TextInput placeholder="Email" style={{ width: 200; height: 40; }} />
  </View>
</Image>
```

Comment: please post some code.

Comment: @Mouser Added in, currently minimal setup atm, reason it is nested inside Image is to apply full background image to current scene

Comment: Check this link out and upvote the answer if it helps!http://stackoverflow.com/a/41381151/718968

Comment: @IrfanAyaz interesting read, but that answer implies triggering keyboard dismiss once certain action happens, i.e. submit. Thats fine, my question is more about asking why does input not blur when I press away from it? At the moment I am confused about this being default behaviour or an issue on my end.

Comment: This is not the default behaviour i suppose! Not for android too.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Unfortunately that is expected behaviour.

You should wrap TextInput inside `ScrollView` (and disable scrolling if needed) and then with property `keyboardShouldPersistTaps="never"`.

Comment: @notgiorgi you need to use `keyboardShouldPersistTaps="never"` now as `false`  was deprecated.

Comment: Using `keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled"` works better in my case. Otherwise keyboard is getting dismissed way too easily. Thanks for sharing this zvona, it was very useful info.

Comment: this does not work for me: react-native version: 51. On iOS

Comment: `keyboardShouldPersistTaps={false}` is deprecated. Use `never` instead.