# RN TextInput not lose it's focus and hide it's keyboad when clicked outside of the input

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-textinput

```
<SafeAreaView style={[styles.mainContainer, Props.style]}>
  <View style={[styles.titleContainer, Props.titleContainerStyle]}>
    <Text style={[styles.title, Props.titleStyle]}>{Props.title}</Text>
  </View>
  <ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps="never">
    {Props.column === (1 || undefined) ? (
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback
        onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}
        accessible={false}>
        <View style={styles.contentContainer}>
          <TextInput
            placeholder="Hello"
            onChangeText={setInputField}
            value={inputField}
            style={[styles.textInput, Props.textInputStyle]}
          />
        </View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    ) : Props.column === 2 ? (
      <View>
        <Text>Input2</Text>
      </View>
    ) : Props.column === 3 ? (
      <View>
        <Text>Input3</Text>
      </View>
    ) : (
      <View>
        <Text>Select Values between and 1 and 3 </Text>
      </View>
    )}
  </ScrollView>
</SafeAreaView>
```

I have searched for the solutions and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41426862/blur-textinput-when-tapped-outside-of-it?rq=1) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39514447/lose-focus-and-dismiss-keyboard-on-clicking-outside-of-the-textinput-field-in-re) but even after trying with what has been mentioned in those links it still does not lose focus and hide the keyboard. ( I checked only in the android emulator )

Answer (score 0):

Remove keyboardShouldPersistTaps

And remove the keyboard.dismiss function with the touchable remove.

Scroll view dismiss the focus when click outside function without any extra things.

Comment: no still its not lose its focus

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to click a Touchable without losing focus, you should be able to just set `keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always"` on the ScrollView.