# How can when clicking on select option the keyboard disappears and the element is selected right away

Tags: react-native

I am working with address select screen, and I want when I click to select the keyboard will disappear and the item I clicked will be "selected" but now when I select it just disappear the keyboard and the item I selected stays not in "selected" state but I have to click 1 more time.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulXRC.png)

Hope to get a solution from everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your component inside ScrollView, or Use Pressable, like this:

```
import {Keyboard, Pressable} from 'react-native'
```

And after that wrap your component like this:

```
<Pressable style={{flex: 1}} onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
      ...rest of the components
```

> **Solution 2:**
> Use ScrollView: wrap your component inside ScrollView and use prop:

**keyboardShouldPersistTaps**

```
<ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps="never" />
```

The same are already shared at this [StackoverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41380651/react-native-dismiss-keyboard-when-focus-out-clicked-somewhere-else-outside-t)

If you find this answer useful, please upvote, thanks, writing from my Android on Vacations, Happy Coding ♥️